# Can't run the custom analyzer_plugin in local project : "Unrecorded error while starting the plugin."

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

I struggle at running a sample demo project and plugin for the `analyzer_plugin`

https://github.com/evaisse/dart_demo_analyzer_plugin

- I create sample demo project named "`demo_analyzed_project`" in (`./example/demo_analyzer_plugin`)
- Which use "`demo_analyzer_plugin`" (in `./`)
- And the attached "`demo_analyzer_plugin_loader`" package in `./tools/analyzer_plugin`

using dart : `Dart SDK version: 2.19.6 (stable) (Tue Mar 28 13:41:04 2023 +0000) on "macos_x64"`

Using Android studio, I got no analysis and I can't get rid of the following error from the analyzer diagnostics webpage :

```
Unrecorded error while starting the plugin.
#0      PluginSession.start (package:analysis_server/src/plugin/plugin_manager.dart:982:22)
#1      PluginInfo.start (package:analysis_server/src/plugin/plugin_manager.dart:219:21)
#2      PluginManager.addPluginToContextRoot (package:analysis_server/src/plugin/plugin_manager.dart:344:23)
```